# Not able to bind Amchart piechart Legend outside the div and also help me for Custom legend as given in description

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I was working on Amcharts PIE chart, and i got problem in binding
 legend outside div and also i need custom Legend for Pie chart

Here I have updated code working of PIE chart [CODE PEN](http://codepen.io/OfficialVikku/pen/rYwrpB)

and I am not able bind as per given style in the ID `#PieDivID` " ,as soon as i remove this style, Legend will appear but not in a right place

```
 `#PieDivID {
  position: absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:25px;
}`
```

and also 
Can someone help me to arrange those legends in this way 
 
Total:4
Pending:4
OnGoing:3
Completed:6

```js
var tripPieChart1 = AmCharts.makeChart( "tripPieChart1", 
      { 
        "hideCredits" : true,
        "color":"#000000",
        "labelsEnabled": true,
        "type": "pie",
        "theme": "light",
        "bold": true,
        "dataProvider": [ {
         "status": "Total",
         "count":4,
         "color": "#FF0F00",
         "bold": true,
        }, {
         "status": "Pending",
         "count":7,"color" : "#9C27B0"
        }, {
         "status": "OnGoing",
         "count":3,  "color": "#FFBE01"
        }, {
         "status": "Completed",
         "count":6, "color": "#00C853"
        }],
        "valueField": "count",
        "titleField": "status",
        "colorField": "color",
        "depth3D": 15,
        "angle": 25,
        "legend":{
           "divId": "PieDivID",
           "autoMargins": false,
          "enabled" : true,
          "maxColumns": 1,
          "generateFromData": true,
         },
        "export": {
          "enabled": false,
         
        }
      } );
```

```css
#tripPieChart1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#PieDivID {
  position: absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:25px;
}
/*I am not able bind as per given style in this #PieDivID , as soon as i remove this style, Legend will appear but not in a right place
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="PieDivID"></div>
<div id="tripPieChart1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a width to the div containing your external legend for it to show up. Adding `min-width: 200px;` was sufficient but adjust as needed.

The order of the legend markers is dependent on the order of the data provider. If you want the legend markers to show up in that order, sort your dataProvider in that order. In your example it's already in the desired order so no additional work is needed.

Demo:

```js
var tripPieChart1 = AmCharts.makeChart("tripPieChart1", {
  "hideCredits": true,
  "color": "#000000",
  "labelsEnabled": true,
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "bold": true,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "status": "Total",
    "count": 4,
    "color": "#FF0F00",
    "bold": true,
  }, {
    "status": "Pending",
    "count": 7,
    "color": "#9C27B0"
  }, {
    "status": "OnGoing",
    "count": 3,
    "color": "#FFBE01"
  }, {
    "status": "Completed",
    "count": 6,
    "color": "#00C853"
  }],
  "valueField": "count",
  "titleField": "status",
  "colorField": "color",
  "depth3D": 15,
  "angle": 25,
  "legend": {
    "divId": "PieDivID",
    "autoMargins": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    //"generateFromData": true, //this is a custom property - not sure what this is for.
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": false,

  }
});
```

```css
#tripPieChart1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#PieDivID {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  min-width: 200px;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="PieDivID"></div>
<div id="tripPieChart1"></div>
```

If you need a custom legend, look at [this example from AmCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/fully-functional-custom-legend-pie-chart/) and modify it to work with your code. You can pretty much copy and paste the code and modify the variable/div references.